# C++ добавление к const char *

Tags: c++, строки

Есть два `const char`

```
const char* filename
const char* path
```

Допустим

```
filename = "fff.txt"
path = "c\desktop\"
```

и как мне объеденить чтоб вышло

```
path = "c\desktop\fff.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто

```
#include <string>

//...

const char *filename = "fff.txt";
const char *path = "c\\desktop\\";

std::string fullname( path );
fullname.append( filename );
```

Если нужно обращаться как к объекту типа `const char *`, то вы можете вызывать функцию `fullname.c_str()`

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    const char *filename = "fff.txt";
    const char *path = "c\\desktop\\";

    std::string fullname( path );
    fullname.append( filename );

    std::cout << fullname << std::endl;
    std::cout << fullname.c_str() << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
c\desktop\fff.txt
c\desktop\fff.txt
```

Comment: Экранировать слеши кто будет?

Comment: @Qwertiy Это вопрос не ко мне.:) Тут копируешь из вопроса простой строковый литерал, так даже его не могут написать корректно.:)

Answer (score 2):

А вот на Си:

http://ideone.com/yVAwTV

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *filename = "fff.txt";
    const char *path = "C:\\desktop\\";

    int n = strlen(path);
    char *res = (char *)malloc(n + strlen(filename) + 1);
    strcpy(res, path);
    strcpy(res+n, filename);

    puts(res);

    free(res);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас GNU, то в подобных случаях очень удобно использовать функцию [asprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf), которая аналогична `sprintf`, но размещает результат своей работы в динамически выделяемой памяти.

Пример:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  const char *path = "/tmp";
  const char *file = "xaxa";
  char *fullname;

  if (asprintf(&fullname, "%s/%s", path, file) == -1)
    exit((perror("asprintf"), EXIT_FAILURE));
  puts(fullname);
  free(fullname);

  return 0;
}
```

Если же у Вас еще нет `asprintf` (или по каким-то соображениям код из `stdio.h` должен быть не `_GNU_SOURCE`), то можете взять, например, такой код:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

static int 
asprintf (char **ps, const char *fmt, ...)
{
  //  puts("my asprintf");
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, fmt);
  int rc = vsnprintf(*ps, 0, fmt, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  if (rc >= 0) {
    if ((*ps = (char *)malloc(rc + 2))) {
      va_start(ap, fmt);
      rc = vsnprintf(*ps, rc + 1, fmt, ap);
      va_end(ap);
    } else
      rc = -1;
  }

  return rc;
}
```

Comment: Ну только не надо забывать что это непереносимая не стандартная функция, которую лучше избегать.

Comment: @AndreyBuran, и куда же она не переносится?

Comment: _GNU_SOURCE включает нестандратные расширения GNU и/или Linux . Соответсвенно за пределы этого множества (а так же возможно на новые версии) этот код не переносится. Конкретно этой функции вы в стандарте C++ не найдёте. Более того, если уж идти до конца, то там где этот макрос поддерживается чаще всего он включается сам по умолчанию (проверил только что на g++ 4.6.3 например)

Comment: @AndreyBuran, я имел в виду переносимость кода `static int 
asprintf (...` (а стандарты по сути мы делаем сами активно включая (или не включая) те или иные фичи в свой код)

Comment: Расскажите это комитету по стандарту и разработчикам платформ. asprintf нет в стандарте, это GNUшное расширениие которого нигде за пределами GNU нет.